# Multiple Python Versions on OS X

Tags: macos, python-2.7

Some functions of apps requires Python 2.7.12 others require 2.7.5 Is it possible to use both of them? The directory in Pythons Framework (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions) does not indicate the individual build. Only the main build. (2.7 = 2.7.5) How apps handle different builds?

Comment: 2.7.12 is a bugfix release; all of the 2.7.x's are.  Can you elaborate on why a function requires an older (buggier) version within the 2.7.x train?  https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2712/

Comment: qBittorrents.app's search engine requires Python 2.7.12, where Viscosity.app doesn't launch on 2.7.12 I thought the same as you: 2.7.12 is an update not an upgrade but... no.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the solution for this problem is... when you download the python updater for OS X from the python website, the folder "Extras" is not included. Manually copy the folder from the previous version e.g. /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/ to /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/ will solve the problem. Don't forget to restore the access rights after copying the folder.